# How these codes work (Constructor And ListView)

Tags: java, android-studio, constructor

I was following the udemy android app development course, In the course, we were writing code to Create A listview and get some data when the user clicks on the list, to do that the teacher uses a thing called Constructor I know how constructors work theoretically but can't understand the way it works in code. It will be great if someone can explain what these lines of codes do.

edit: Full Code is here https://github.com/atilsamancioglu/A14-LandmarkBook

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Globals {


private static Globals instance;

private Bitmap chosenImage;

private Globals(){


}

public void setData(Bitmap chosenImage){
    this.chosenImage=chosenImage;

}


public Bitmap getData(){
    return this.chosenImage;


}


public static Globals getInstance() {

    if(instance==null){

        instance = new Globals();

    }

    return instance;
}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are special methods invoked when an object is created and are used to initialize them. 
A constructor can be used to provide initial values for object attributes.
You can think of constructors as methods that will set up your class by default, so you don’t need to repeat the same code every time.
In your codes, you can define the constructor as below(it may be unrelated, it's just an example):

```
private Globals(int id){
return chosenImage.setId(id);
}
```

The constructor is called when you create an object using the new keyword:

```
Globals objectGlobe = new Globals(000008);
```

Also a single class can have multiple constructors with different numbers of parameters.
The setter methods inside the constructors can be used to set the attribute values.
It's not bad to be mentioned that; Java automatically provides a default constructor, so all classes have a constructor, whether one is specifically defined or not.